# Label on the side of box plot in R - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add few labels on the side of the boxplot like image1. I have generated box plot in ggplot (image2). Please help me on the solution.

Please check my code for generating the boxplot,

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(runif(100, min=0, max=10000))
names(d) <- "randnum"

box1 <- ggplot(d, aes_string(x=factor(0), y=d$randnum)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0) + geom_jitter(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, color = "tomato")

box1 <- box1 +  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title =element_blank(),
                      axis.text.x =element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

box1
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Thanks,
SJB.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to make the graph larger and write the text *in* the plot? I suspect that would make it a lot easier.

Comment: @Jimbou I wanted to try only with ggplot for understanding purpose.

Comment: @Nova could you please explain me with the code for better understanding.

Comment: @Ggamba's answer is what I was thinking - having the labels inside the plot vastly simplifies the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `ggrepel` package, and create the texts and position we need.

We first need to calculate the `y` position of the labels, and I hope I got those right, change if needed.

Note that in this form many parts of the plot are hard coded and won't work in some cases, in particular the `xlim`s are hand picked for my particular screen, and may need to be tweaked.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
d <- data.frame(runif(100, min=0, max=10000))
names(d) <- "randnum"

first_quantile <- quantile(d$randnum, .25)
third_quantile <- quantile(d$randnum, .75)

inner_fence <- third_quantile + (third_quantile - first_quantile) * 1.5
outer_fence <- inner_fence + (third_quantile - first_quantile) * 1.5

fences <- data.frame(labels = c('first quartile', 'third quartile', 'inner fence', 'outer fence'),
                     y = c(first_quantile, third_quantile, 
                           inner_fence, outer_fence))

ggplot(d, aes_string(x=factor(0), y=d$randnum)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, color = "tomato") +
  geom_text_repel(data = fences, aes(x = 1.45, y = y, label = labels), nudge_x = 500, segment.color = 'green', xlim = c(NA, 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.85,1.5)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title =element_blank(),
        axis.text.x =element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try

```
# your data
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(runif(100, min=0, max=10000))
names(d) <- "randnum"

# the plot
box1 <- ggplot(d, aes_string(x=factor(0), y=d$randnum)) + 
               geom_boxplot(alpha = 0) +
               geom_jitter(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, color = "tomato")

# the data for the annotation
d2 <- data.frame(y=boxplot(d,plot = F)$stats,
                 x=1.4,
                 xend=1.5)
d2 <- rbind.data.frame(d2, c(d2[4,1]+ (d2[4,1] - d2[2,1]) * 1.5, 1.4, 1.5))
d2 <- rbind.data.frame(d2, c(d2[6,1]+ (d2[4,1] - d2[2,1]) * 1.5, 1.4, 1.5))
d2$label <- c("Min", "1Q", "Median", "3Q", "Max", "Inner", "Outer")
# and the plot
box1 + scale_y_continuous(name="", sec.axis =dup_axis(name = "", 
                                                      breaks = d2$y,
                                                      labels = d2$label)) +
       geom_segment(aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=y), data = d2, inherit.aes = F)
```

[image]